# Can I contribute to a 401k, Roth 401k and Roth IRA at the same time?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, roth-401k

My company provides me access to 401k, and I am contributing the maximum allowed in that 401k. In addition I also have Roth IRA (I qualify for it because of income less than $193000). Recently, my company has said now we have option of regular 401k or Roth 401k. Now, I am wondering if I can contribute to all three accounts? I know I would be subjected to maximum limit of 401k, but is it still allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I have a Simple IRA can I also contribute to a Traditional IRA and/or Roth IRA?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13491/if-i-have-a-simple-ira-can-i-also-contribute-to-a-traditional-ira-and-or-roth-ir)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The difference of 401(k) with IRA vs multiple types of IRA seems sufficiently different to me to justify a new question. @EllieKesselman

Answer (score 13):

Yes, [you're allowed to contribute to both a Roth 401k and a regular 401k](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-on-Designated-Roth-Accounts#4); it's fairly common to do so for the purposes of diversification.  You can [also contribute to a Roth IRA](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-on-Designated-Roth-Accounts#7), assuming you're under the income limits.

Note that your employers' contributions to your 401k (like a match) are always pre-tax, not Roth.